# How do I expose a private link for rds that can be used by an instance in another vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services

It is possible to expose a private link for AWS RDS that can used by an instance in another VPC. Currently when I go to the Endpoint services section it only give me a list of network load balancers. is such thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to create a private connection between RDS and an instance in another VPC would be to set up [VPC peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) between the two VPCs.

A normal VPC endpoint gives a private connection to an AWS service. A VPC private link allows you to publish an endpoint which others can use like a VPC endpoint.

Check also this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871544/what-is-difference-between-aws-vpc-private-link-and-vpc-peering)

Also check if the service is [available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html#vpce-interface-limitations) in your region and the [VPC interface limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html#vpce-interface-limitations).

Comment: How do I setup for RDS a vpc private link

Answer (score 0):

From horse's mouth/ AWS document:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ec2-bastion-host/